# Use variables outside the subprocess in bash

Tags: bash, function, shell

There's a `getStrings()` function that calls `getPage()` function that returns some html page. That html is piped through `egrep` and `sed` combination to get only 3 strings. Then I try to put every string into separate variable `link`, `profile`, `gallery` respectively using `while read..` construction. But it works only inside the `while...done` loop because it runs in subprocess. What should I do to use those variables outside the `getStrings()` function?

```
getStrings() {
    local i=2
    local C=0
    getPage $(getPageLink 1 $i) |
    egrep *some expression that results in 3 strings* | 
        while read line; do
            if (( (C % 3) == 0 )); then 
                link=$line
            elif (( (C % 3) == 1 )); then
                profile=$line
            else
                gallery=$line
            fi
            C=$((C+1)) #Counter
        done
}
```

Comment: Investigate `shopt -s lastpipe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: don't run the loop in a subprocess :)

To actually *accomplish* that, you can use process substitution.

```
while read line; do
    ...
done < <(getPage $(getPageLink 1 $i) | egrep ...)
```

For the curious, a POSIX-compatible way is to use a named pipe (and its possible that `bash` uses named pipes to implement process substitution):

```
mkfifo pipe
getPage $(getPageLink 1 $i) | egrep ... > pipe &
while read line; do
    ...
done < pipe
```

Starting in `bash` 4.2, you can just set the `lastpipe` option, which causes the last command in a pipeline to run in the current shell, rather than a subshell.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
getPage $(getPageLink 1 $i) | egrep ... | while read line; do
   ...
done
```

---

However, using a while loop is not the best way to set the three variables. It's easier to just call `read` three times within a command group, so that they all read from the same stream. In any of the three scenarios above, replace the while loop with

```
{ read link; read profile; read gallery; }
```

If you want to be a little more flexible, put the names of the variables you might want to read in an array:

```
fields=( link profile gallery )
```

then replace the while loop with this for loop instead:

```
for var in "${fields[@]}"; do read $var; done
```

This lets you easily adjust your code, should the pipeline ever return more or fewer lines, by just editing the `fields` array to have the appropriate field names.

Answer (score 0):

One more solving using array:

```
getStrings() {
array_3=( `getPage | #some function
    egrep | ...` ) #pipe conveyor
}
```